# Issues wiring a remote photocell to an LED light

Tags: lighting, led

I have had a set of around 10-12 external LED lights, which consume max 25W @12VDC - which I'm looking to control using an external photocell (and looking to use one per light as they're in different areas e.g. under thick trees where it gets darker quicker).

I bought this remote photocell unit (datasheet and recommended wiring diagram below):

[image: Technical Info]

[image: Recommended wiring diagram]

As seen in the datasheet the remote cell states it's sutiable for applications up to 30W -so well within the scope of handling my 25W max lights. They operate at the same voltage which I found convenient.

However, after wiring following the above diagram my system is not working. When I first turn on my power source and cover my remote cell with something dark (duct tape) it turns the light on for 1-5seconds before shutting off. After this, I can never get it to come back on or stay on - even after say midnight. I'm quite perplexed as to what the issue could be here as everything seems compatible.

Note the wiring distances in my scenario between sensor, light and power supply is all less than 1m and on 16AWG copper.

Comment: specifying the exact brand/model number may help someone find some details you may have missed in the instructions, such as the settings [RMDman is suggesting you look for](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/260680/34147).

Comment: https://www.lumenalights.com/shop/product/external-photocell-unit-dusk-to-dawn-12v/

@RMDman

Answer (score 1):

If your power source is constant, the problem is most likely not with your wiring, but with the sensor box. Many have adjustments for time and sensitivity. Look at the instruction sheet for those adjustments as well as a "problem and solution " grid.